# La columna: 'existencias_totales' en field list es ambigua en consulta inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 3 tablas, pero en 2 tengo existencias_totales, quien pueda decirme mi error :)

```
SELECT *, existencias_totales as c_existencias_totales, descripcion 
FROM productos a 
INNER JOIN asignar_productos b ON b.folioProducto=a.folioProducto 
INNER JOIN productos_disponible c ON a.folioProducto=c.folioProducto 
WHERE b.folioProducto LIKE "a123"
```

```
#1052 - La columna: 'existencias_totales' en field list es ambigua
```

Answer (score 1):

necesitas decirle a la consulta a cual campo de las 2 tablas es al que le va a cambiar el nombre en este caso seria **a.existencias_totales as c_existencias_totales**, porque si no estarías tratando de cambiar los dos campos que tienen el mismo nombre

asi quedaria tu consulta

```
SELECT *, a.existencias_totales as c_existencias_totales, descripcion FROM productos a INNER JOIN asignar_productos b ON b.folioProducto=a.folioProducto INNER JOIN productos_disponible c ON a.folioProducto=c.folioProducto WHERE b.folioProducto LIKE "a123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te indica que una columna es ambigua, es por que el motor:

- Encuentra que ese mismo nombre existe en mas de una tabla
- No identifica a cual de las N tablas que estés involucrando pertenece ya que solo la estás invocando por medio de su nombre lo cual es parcial y confuso de resolver

La forma mas simple de tratar con esto es que sigas la sintaxis de:

```
tablaNombre.columna
```

De esta forma aunque en tus N tablas la columna se llame igual (que para nada es recomendable) el motor sabrá diferenciarlas.

Answer (score 0):

miiwtwo:

Sería bueno colocar la estructura de las tablas en las que estás haciendo un INNER JOIN. Lo más probable es que entre las 3 tablas:

productos asignar_productos productos_disponible

El campo existencias_totales exista en más de una, por lo que al seleccionarlo en el SELECT te dirá que es ambiguo ya que no sabe a que existencias_totales te refieres si al de una tabla u otra.

Lo mejor en estos casos es utilizar alias en el FROM o el nombre de la tabla completo. Ya qué, por ejemplo, si tienes existencias_totales tanto en la tabla productos como productos_disponible podrás hacer un select de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT productos.existencias_totales, productos_disponible.existencias_totales
```

Con el SELECT * traes todos los campos de las 3 tablas, por lo que al volver a hacer un existencias_totales as c_existencias_totales aunque coloques un alias en el select no sabe a que existencias_totales te refieres si al de una tabla u otra.

Espero haberte ayudado.